# Finding the cause why a laptop wakes itself from sleep

Tags: laptop, sleep, wake-up

My new Windows 7 64bit laptop keeps waking up from sleep. I tried various things and still it wakes up:

- Disconnecting the mouse\keyboard
- Disconnecting it from the LAN
- Keeping it with the lid closed

How can I find the reason for its wakeup?

Comment: Do you possibly have WiFi or a 3G card on the machine? That's usually what does it.

Answer (score 6):

Is your network card allowed to wake the computer?

2. Open Device Manager
3. Open Network Adapters and navigate to your network card.
4. Right click on the network card and select properties.
5. Go to the **Power Management tab** and untick the option to prevent your network card from waking up Windows.

A few commands to see what the last wakeup events were, and which device caused it:

```
powercfg -lastwake
powercfg -devicequery wake_armed
```

Also check in Control Panel:

- Power Settings, Change Plan Settings, Change Advanced Power Settings

... walk the list there and see if anything looks promising.

Answer (score 3):

- Take a look at the Event Log
- Check if there are scheduled tasks

Comment: please provide all steps how to view event log

Answer (score 1):

*This comment is in regards to **NEWER** laptops.*

**IF** it wakes up and stays awake, disregard this comment ...

**Else,** it is most likely attempting to keep your 'apps' updated using Intel's new *Smart Connect Technology.*

How it works:

> *"While your computer is asleep, Intel Smart Connect Technology wakes the system periodically and re-establishes network connectivity. This
>   enables your applications that receive data from the Internet ... to quickly sync with the cloud
>   service and update your system. After the content is updated, the
>   system automatically transitions back to sleep mode."*

Link:  http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/smart-connect-technology.html

Answer (score 0):

## Another reasons:

1) For laptops: Mouse or Keyboard click causes wake-up. **Device Manager>Mouse>Properties>Power Management>** uncheck the checkbox "**allow this device to wake computer**". (same may be needed for KEYBOARD,WIFI,NETWORK adapters, AC adapter...

2) Laptops (at least mine) wake up whenever i plug-out from power and plug-in back. So, it seems, stopping electricity and returning it, causes laptop to wake up.

3) other good reasons listed here too: http://www.howtogeek.com/193246/what-keeps-waking-my-computer-up/